# Как узнать реальную позицию объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существует 9 квадратов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которые являются дочерними пустого объекта Squares:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Позиция и размер этого пустого объекта стандартные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если изменить размер пустого объекта с (1; 1; 1) на (0,5; 0,5; 0,5), то тогда дочерние объекты уменьшаться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синие были, красные стали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Позиции в редакторе допустим левого в углу верхнем квадрата не изменились:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но реальная позиция, как видно на рисунке выше изменилась. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать эту новую реальную позицию?

Comment: [Локальные позиции](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) не изменяются, но [мировые](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) меняются, тебе в инспекторе отображаются локальные, если выбран элемент, у которого есть родитель.

Comment: @KOTlK, не могли ли вы, пожалуйста, подсказать как узнать эту мировую позицию через код. Я нахожу допустим позицию через transform.position.x. А как поменять это не понимаю.

Comment: Я для кого ссылки оставил? Менять нужно не x,y,z, а весь вектор transform.position. Оси у него readonly

Comment: @KOTlK, Спасибо Большое! Я всё понял